# NoJson found on an http request on play 2.3.2

Tags: json, scala, http, curl, playframework

i'm writing a Play 2.3.2 application using Scala.
In my controller i had a method which get the json object from the request.
The implementation is like the following:

```
def firstTags = Action.async { request => 
     def elaborate(n: Int): Future[Result] = {//some implementation}
      //get the json Object
       val jsonObject = request.body.asJson
       //parse the json object
       jsonObject match {
         case Some(json) => json \ "number" match {
           case x: JsNumber => elaborate(x.as[Int])
           case _ => Future{BadRequest}
         }
         case None => Future{BadRequest("Need a Json")}
       }
     }
```

In my route files i had:

```
 GET /recommendation/statistic/first @recommendationsystem.controllers.manager.StatisticsController.firstTags
```

When i try to call the method with the curl i get always a "Need a Json" response.
I call my server with curl like the following:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"number": 3}' -X GET http://localhost:9000/recommendation/statistic/first
```

What's wrong??

Comment: Try using POST or PUT instead of GET

Comment: I try to use POST and now it works.
But logically POST is wrong, because my method don't store data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GET shouldn't have body. look at [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body).
POST method is not only for modify the server state, but also to process data.
From [RFC 2616 - HTTP/1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.5):

> The POST method is used to request that the origin server accept the
> entity enclosed in the request as a new subordinate of the resource
> identified by the Request-URI in the Request-Line. POST is designed
> to allow a uniform method to cover the following functions:
>
> - Annotation of existing resources;
> - Posting a message to a bulletin board, newsgroup, mailing list,
>   or similar group of articles;
> - Providing a block of data, such as the result of submitting a
>   form, to a data-handling process;
> - Extending a database through an append operation.
>
> The actual function performed by the POST method is determined by the
> server and is usually dependent on the Request-URI. [...]